# MYSQL PHP PDO how get 1 record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i got a problem with getting value from Database:

```
$marka=$_POST['marka'];

$marka=$connection->quote($marka);

$id_marki=$connection->query('Select id from Model where nazwa='.$marka)->fetch();

echo $id_marki['id'];
```

Echo show me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $connection->prepare('Select id from Model where nazwa=?');
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['marka']));
$id = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $id;
```

Comment: Sorry bud, but your question is "how to get one record". So I answered. While "why does it show nothing" is another.